# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_links}) using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to build a simple example with react and spring boot. However i can't get the react part to render the response.

I am getting this back from the spring boot application:

```
{_links: {…}}
_links:
articles: {href: "http://localhost:8080/api/articles"}
profile: {href: "http://localhost:8080/api/profile"}
```

using this code I will get the below error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_links}) using hooks
import React from "react";
import useFetch from "./useFetch";

export default function DataLoader(props) {
  const data = useFetch("/api");
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Testing</h1>
      <ul>
        {data}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Adapting the code for that error to loop the array gives another error.

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): data.map is not a function

import React from "react";
import useFetch from "./useFetch";

export default function DataLoader(props) {
  const data = useFetch("/api");
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Testing</h1>
      <ul>
        {data.map(data => <div>{data.keys}</div>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` return is an `Object`

If you want to iterate over just the keys you'll want:

```
import React from "react";
import useFetch from "./useFetch";

export default function DataLoader(props) {
  const data = useFetch("/api");
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Testing</h1>
      <ul>
        {Object.keys(data).map(key => <div>{key}</div>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note the `Object.keys` you're mapping on instead of the `data`

Comment: Great that works. How would I then get the value inside href?

Comment: You'll probably want to use `Object.entries` `{Object.entries(data._links).map(([key, { href }]) => <a href={href}>{key}</a>)`

Answer (score 1):

`data` is an object but `.map` is an array function.

Given the structure you've shared you probably need to somehow use `Object.keys` which given an object returns an array with the object's keys as members:

```js
import React from "react";
import useFetch from "./useFetch";

export default function DataLoader(props) {
  const data = useFetch("/api");
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Testing</h1>
      <ul>
        {Object.keys(data._links).map(key => <a {...data._links[key]}>{key}</a>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What this would do is go through all entries in `_links` and create an anchor with props given by the contents of `_links[key]` (e.g. if key is `articles` it would be all entries under `data._links.articles`) `{...data._links[key]}` just means expand the object as props for the anchor.

Given your data this should produce links like:

`<a href="http://localhost:8080/api/articles">articles</a>`